# Synology + 12345678

Tags: passwords, synology

I am facing a weird problem with synology Diskstation.

Problem:

Suppose I created a user that is "Test" with the password "testinguser"
I see user created and I can see synology logs for it.

Now if I change password of above user and see logs, I can see that password change perfect 
(for example change password from "testinguser" -> "testingagain"

If I change password to string "12345678", then a problem comes as synology does not detect the password change and I can still see  the old password is active and usable!

Any idea?

Comment: Have you reported this problem to Synology.  I can only assume the OS is silently rejecting the password for some reason.

Comment: Do you have minimum password length set of greater than 8 characters? https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/tutorials/478#t3

Comment: I have no such limitation, i can set other password .. only 12345678 is get rejected and i dnt know how to debug this situation !!

Answer (score -1):

Can you create a new user with that password?
Then you do not CHANGE the password but then you CREATE a new password. Then there will no longer be an 'old' password, so no other password is usable.

*Because of my 'low' reputation I cannot comment, thats why this is typed in an answer...*

Comment: Leaving comments as answers is a great way to lose reputation. Invest some time in this site and you'll be able to comment. It's just 50 rep that you need to comment.

Comment: No problem as you typed as answer..( Yes i can create new user with this password) but if i want to change password to 12345678 then it doesn't work.

Comment: Also my curiosity why 12345678 password do not accepted and how we can find where it get rejected.

Comment: I can try it on my own disk station. Which DSM are you using?